# libz.so preventing make in OpenCV 3 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Cuda

Tags: nvidia, cuda, opencv

OpenCV is depending on a nonexistent symbolic link from

```
/usr/lib/libz.so
```

I cannot install OpenCV 3.0.0 3.1.0 or 3.2.0 on my work computer which has Cuda installed. On a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 following the instructions in [this](https://github.com/cesco345/StemApks/blob/master/TutorialsNotebook%20(1).ipynb) link OpenCV installed perfectly fine without Cuda (and changing the version downloaded to be 3.0.0.

Now installing on my work computer I keep receiving this error upon running the make after making the makefile (cmake). The cmake command is working, the command make afterwards is the core problem.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D WITH_QT=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D WITH_OPENGL=OFF -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
    -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON ..

make
```

Error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libz.so', needed by 'lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1283: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Upon inspection of /usr/lib/libz.so it is a dangling symbolic link, when viewing where it is supposed to link to.

```
ls /usr/lib/libz.so -lhA
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 May  9 09:29 /usr/lib/libz.so -> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so

cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
julian@ThinkPad-W540:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu$ ls
audit              libformw.so.5.9             libpanelw.so.5.9
gconv              libgpm.so.2                 libpcreposix.so.3
libcuda.so         libmenuw.so.5               libpcreposix.so.3.13.2
libcuda.so.1       libmenuw.so.5.9             libtic.so.5
libcuda.so.375.66  libnvidia-opencl.so.1       libtic.so.5.9
libdb-5.3.so       libnvidia-opencl.so.375.66
libformw.so.5      libpanelw.so.5
```

I have tried reinstalling the [package libz is in](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libz.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=any)

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev --reinstall
```

and still have no luck with the same error

```
*** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libz.so', needed by 'lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0'.  Stop.
```

So I'm at the stage of feeling thoroughly stuck, I've tried linking /usr/lib/libz.so to cuda files in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu as the required /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so is not there and is not there after reinstalling zlib.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the machine actually 32-bit, or 64-bit? I don't recall a link `/usr/lib/libz.so` existing by default - AFAIK `ld` normally looks in the architecture-dependent `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` or `/usr/lib/x84_64-linux-gnu/` directly

Comment: The machine is a 64 bit architecture.
Entering `uname -a` outputs: 
`Linux ThinkPad-W540 4.4.0-81-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 14 08:17:06 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

The primary error says that OpenCV is depending on the sym link of libz.so.
`No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libz.so', needed by 'lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0'.`

Comment: Well unless CUDA needs some kind of 32-bit support that I'm not aware of, I'd suggest just removing the dangling symlink and then starting over - you will need to make sure the link location isn't cached (for example, by deleting the cmake `build` dir if you've used one). Hopefully cmake will then pick up the correct location in `/usr/lib/x84_64-linux-gnu/`

Comment: Okay, I removed the symlink and the build directory. I then recreated the build directory and ran the cmake command which rand fine. Afterwards I ran `make` and encountered the same error at `[  4%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/opencl_kernels_core.cpp.o` `make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/julian/libz.so', needed by 'lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

It seems that the symbolic link of libz.so in /usr/lib is broken.

I removed that symbolic link and created the new link to the directory where my libz.so is located and run `make` again and everything worked as expected.